# How do i assign a value to a char?

Tags: delphi-2010

Quite a silly question, but I've been stuck on this for quite a while now. I want to copy the first letter of a string and store it in a char variable, then test whether this variable is uppercase or lowercase with the use of an 'IN' statement. I get an error of incompatible types when I try to store the first letter into a char though, and I'm not exactly sure as to how I would get around this.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  S: string;
  C: char;
begin
  S := ...;
  C := S[1];
  if C in ['A'..'Z'] then
  begin
    ...
  end
  else if C in ['a'..'z'] then
  begin
    ... 
  end;
end;
```

That being said, note that `Char` is an alias for `WideChar` in Delphi 2009+, and you shouldn't use Wide characters in Sets, as they will get truncated. In this case, you can use the [`CharInSet()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.CharInSet) function instead:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

var
  S: string;
  C: char;
begin
  S := ...;
  C := S[1];
  if CharInSet(C, ['A'..'Z']) then
  begin
    ...
  end
  else if CharInSet(C, ['a'..'z']) then
  begin
    ... 
  end;
end;
```

Or better, use the  [`IsUpper()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Character.IsUpper) and [`IsLower()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Character.IsLower) functions:

```
uses
  ..., Character;

var
  S: string;
  C: char;
begin
  S := ...;
  C := S[1];
  if IsUpper(C) then
  begin
    ...
  end
  else if IsLower(C) then
  begin
    ... 
  end;
end;
```

```
uses
  ..., Character;

var
  S: string;
begin
  S := ...;
  if IsUpper(S, 1) then
  begin
    ...
  end
  else if IsLower(S, 1) then
  begin
    ... 
  end;
end;
```